# Awk count frequency

Tags: awk

Hey i want to count the amount of data in a certain column in awk.
an example dataset is
`2 5 8

  1 3 7

8 5 9`
and I want to count the frequency of the 5 in the second colum. This is what i tried that didn't work

```
{
total = 0;
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
{
  if(i==2)
{if($i==5) {total++;}

}
  printf("%s  ", total);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following:

```
awk '{ if ($2==5) count++ } END { print count }'
```

Comment: You can move the condition out of the block: `awk '$2 == 5 {count++} END {print count}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR == 1 {ind = 0} $2 == 5 {ind++} END {print ind}' testdata.txt
```