# how to count occurences in specific column and sum it up

Tags: awk

I've just started using awk,

so this is the input

```
No | Band 
1  | 2G
2  | 3G
3  | 4G
4  | 2G
5  | 2G
```

and the output is

```
Band | Sum
2G   | 3
3G   | 1
4G   | 1
```

Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Awk count frequency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921746/awk-count-frequency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
echo "No | Band 
1  | 2G
2  | 3G
3  | 4G
4  | 2G
5  | 2G "\
| awk -F'|' 'NR>1{
      band[$2]++
  }
  END{
    print "Band | Sum"
      for (x in band){
        print x" | " band[x]
      }
  }'
```

output

```
Band | Sum
 3G | 1
 2G | 3
 4G | 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tail -n +2 input.txt | cut -d'|' -f2 | sort | uniq -c
      3  2G
      1  3G
      1  4G
```

Comment: you need to add some more pipes and commands to switch the column order and get a header row and put a "|" between fields. Maybe a sed and an echo?

Comment: @EdMorton: that's true, but SO isn't a free programming service so I left the trivial parts as an exercise.  :)